# simple parallel processing in perl

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I have a few blocks of code, inside a function of some object, that can run in parallel and speed things up for me.

I tried using `subs::parallel` in the following way (all of this is in a body of a function):

```
my $is_a_done = parallelize { 
                              # block a, do some work
                              return 1;
                             };
my $is_b_done = parallelize { 
                              # block b, do some work
                              return 1;
                             };
my $is_c_done = parallelize { 
                              # block c depends on a so let's wait (block)
                              if ($is_a_done) {
                               # do some work
                              };
                              return 1;
                             };
my $is_d_done = parallelize { 
                              # block d, do some work
                              return 1;
                             };

if ($is_a_done && $is_b_done && $is_c_done && $is_d_done) {
 # just wait for all to finish before the function returns
}
```

First, notice I use `if` to wait for threads to block and wait for previous thread to finish when it's needed (a better idea? the `if` is quite ugly...).

Second, I get an error:

```
Thread already joined at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/subs/parallel.pm line 259.
Perl exited with active threads:
    1 running and unjoined
    -1 finished and unjoined
    3 running and detached
```

Comment: Interesting.  The problem is that `$is_a_done` is checked in two different threads, which is a documented misuse/caveat of `subs::parallel`:  *You shouldn't pass to another thread/parallelized subroutines previous return values from other parallelized subroutines without reading their values.*

I admit I did not find the caveat to be very *clearly* documented in the 0.8 version of `subs::parallel`, however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't seen `subs::parallel` before, but given that it's doing all of the thread handling for you, and it seems to be doing it *wrong*, based on the error message, I think it's a bit suspect.

Normally I wouldn't just suggest throwing it out like that, but what you're doing really isn't any *harder* with the plain threads interface, so why not give that a shot, and simplify the problem a bit? At the same time, I'll give you an answer to the other part of your question.

```
use threads;
my @jobs;
push @jobs, threads->create(sub {
  # do some work
});

push @jobs, threads->create(sub {
  # do some other work
});

# Repeat as necessary :)

$_->join for @jobs; # Wait for everything to finish.
```

You need something a little bit more intricate if you're using the return values from those subs (simply switching to a hash would help a good deal) but in the code sample you provided, you're ignoring them, which makes things easy.

Comment: I created subs instead of using code blocks (looks much cleaner) and updated my question to a slightly different one - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448167/basic-thread-hanlding-in-perl