# Thread synchronization/scheduling in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, synchronization, scheduling

I have a perl object with a few functions in it. Each functions is called once from the main program. I would like to run some of the functions in parallel to save time. I can't run all of them together since some functions depend on the results of previous functions.

I thought of something like this:

1. For each function keep a flag that is initialized to false and is set to true by the function when it ends (e.g. the last line in `func1` would be `$is_func1_done = 1`).
2. Start each function with a loop that waits until all the flags of the functions it depends on are true. For example: if `func1` depends on `func2` and `func3` then:

   ```
    sub func1 {
     while (!($is_func2_done && $is_func3_done)) {
      # do nothing
     } 
     # do work
    }
   ```

Then I can start immediately a thread for each function, but the actual work of each function will start only when it's ready. Does this make sense? Do I need any locks here on the flags? Is using such `while` loops common? -- the term busy waiting comes to mind... maybe most of my CPU time will be spent on these `while`s? Is there a more standard solution to this?

Comment: Very, very closely related to discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448167/basic-thread-hanlding-in-perl

Answer (score 3):

> Does this make sense?

Yes - each task knows its preconditions, and waits for them to be met before executing.  It's one of a number of valid designs, though you might find it difficult to scale as the number of tasks grow and their interdependencies grow more complex.

> Do I need any locks here on the flags?

Yes.  The flags need to be [shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html), so that one thread can manipulate them and another see it, and shared variables need to be `lock()`ed to be used safely.

> Is using such while loops common? -- the term busy waiting comes to mind

Sadly yes, but *Don't Do That, Please.*  Shared variables in perl can serve as *condition variables* through which threads can send notifications to one another:

```
sub func1 {
    {
        lock(%shared_state);
        until ($shared_state{ "func2 done" } and $shared_state{ "func3 done" }) {
            cond_wait(%shared_state);
        }
    }
    # do work -- note that %shared_state is unlocked

    # now tell others that we're done
    lock(%shared_state);
    $shared_state{ "func1 done" } = 1;
    cond_broadcast(%shared_state);
    # %shared_state will be unlocked, and broadcast delivered when we leave this scope
}
```

When you `cond_wait`, the shared variable is unlocked and your thread is put to sleep.  No need to busy loop.

> Is there a more standard solution to this?

`$thr->join`, as [Sinan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470184/thread-synchronization-scheduling-in-perl/3470449#3470449), is an easy and natural way to wait for a specific thread to finish running.  [Thread::Semaphore](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Semaphore.html) can serve a similar but more complex function (and, helpfully, can be initialized to values less than zero).  A common need to "wait for these 5 threads to finish something" can be achieved with a [Thread::Barrier](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Thread-Barrier/).  TMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$thr->join` to wait for a thread to finish.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use threads;

my @threads = map threads->create($_), qw( func1 func2 );
$_->join for @threads;

my $thr3 = threads->create('func3');
$thr3->join;

sub func1 {
    for (1 .. 5) {
        print "func1\n";
        sleep 1 + rand 3;
    }
    return;
}

sub func2 {
    for (1 .. 5) {
        print "func2\n";
        sleep 1 + rand 2;
    }
    return;
}

sub func3 {
    print "Time to do some work\n";
}
```

I don't know if it is *common* to use such `while` loops: I would not.

Comment: this far I know... but is "scheduling" with such while loops a smart move?