# Perl multithread file / list comparison

Tags: multithreading, string, perl, file, list

My question revolves around the comparison of two files containing big lists of strings (7mio and 3mio). What I need to do is compare each element in one list (called "database") to every element of the other list (called "reference").

I wrote a very basic script for this, but because of the huge amount of comparisons (~3 trillion), I would like to parallelize the search. Since both files are quite big, my idea was to load them into two independent arrays (@reference and @dbPep) only once and then use a subroutine to compare chunks of the lists in separate threads, i.e. 0 to 1000000 in thread 1, 1000001 - 2000000 in thread 2 and so on. The chunk size is determined by the number of threads, whereas the last one gets also what is left over after using modulo. Output should be printed to STDOUT so that it can be piped to a file, the order of results is NOT important.

Now, my problem resides in starting the threads correctly and dynamically depending on the $ARGV input.

Here's what I have so far, multi-threading, however does not really work yet so I commented it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Thread;

    $minLength      = $ARGV[0];
    $numThreads         = $ARGV[1];
    my $reference_File  = $ARGV[2];
    my $peptideDB_File  = $ARGV[3];

    if ($minLength == ""){$minLength = 6;}

    print STDERR ("Threads:\t".$numThreads."\n");
    print STDERR ("Reference:\t".$reference_File."\n");
    print STDERR ("peptide DB:\t".$peptideDB_File."\n----------------\n");
    print STDERR ("Loading reference...\n");

# Load reference peptides
    open (REF,$reference_File) || die ("File not found!");
    @reference = ();
    while (<REF>) {
        chomp;
        my @refPeptide = split("\t");
        if($refPeptide[1] eq "Sequence") {next;}
        push(@reference,$refPeptide[1]);
    }
    close (REF);
    print STDERR ("Done!\n");
    print STDERR ("Length:".@reference."\n");
    print STDERR ("Loading peptide database...\n");


# Open peptide DB to check
    open (PEP,$peptideDB_File) || die ("File not found!");
    @dbID  = ();
    @dbPep = ();
    while (<PEP>) {
        chomp;
        my @dbPeptide = split("\t");
        if($dbPeptide[1] eq "Sequence") {next;}
        push(@dbID,$dbPeptide[0]);
        push(@dbPep,$dbPeptide[1]);
    }
    close (PEP);
print STDERR ("Done!\n");
    print STDERR ("Length:".@dbPep."\n");
    print STDERR ("Starting analysis...\n");
    print STDERR ("(This can take a while)\n");
    print STDERR ("----------------\n");

#my %ref = map { $_ => 1 } @reference;

    my $dbLength        = @dbPep;
    my $rest            = $dbLength % $numThreads;
    my $chunkStart      = 0;
    my $chunkLength     = ($dbLength - $rest) / $numThreads;
    my $chunkEnd        = $chunkLength;

    #print STDERR($chunkEnd."\n");
    &peptideCheck($chunkStart,$chunkEnd);

    #for (my $i=0;$i<$numThreads;$i++) {
#       if ($i == $numThreads-1) {$chunkEnd += $rest;};
#       new Thread \&peptideCheck, $chunkStart, $chunkEnd;
#       $chunkStart += $chunkLength;
#       $chunkEnd   += $chunkLength;
#   }
    print STDERR ("----------------\nFinished!\n");
    sub peptideCheck {
        my @params = @_;
        for (my $j=@params[0]; $j<@params[1];$j++){
            if (length($dbPep[$j]) < $minLength) {next;}
            if ( grep { $_ eq $dbPep[$j]} @reference ) {
                #print STDERR ("RefCall:\n".$peptideCandidate[1]."\n");
                next;
            }
            else {
                #print STDERR ("Found novel peptide:\n");
                print (">".$dbID[$j]."\n".$dbPep[$j]."\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are (very) short examples of my files, the first being database, the second reference.

```
Protein_Name    Sequence    Unique_ID   Monoisotopic_Mass   Predicted_NET   Tryptic_Name
IPI:80000000.1  MGSTSEK 1   738,321789  0,0756  t1.1
IPI:80000001.1  MFLCSSFIFHHDCEASPAMLNCG 2   2559,0512972    0,5426  t1.1
IPI:80000002.1  MIVR    3   517,3046228 0,0924  t1.1
IPI:80000002.1  MIVRPPQPC   4   1039,5306652    0,2739  t1.2
IPI:80000002.1  PPQPC   5   540,2366066 0,1163  t2.1
IPI:80000003.1  MPVLMEK 6   846,4343096 0,2742  t1.1
IPI:80000003.1  MPVLMEKGGGR 7   1173,5998042    0,2599  t1.2
IPI:80000003.1  MPVLMEKGGGREPECSSPLGEQTR    8   2587,2192178    0,2881  t1.3
IPI:80000003.1  MPVLMEKGGGREPECSSPLGEQTRVASVGTCWIEVR    9   3887,878977 0,3859  t1.4


Protein_Name    Sequence    Unique_ID   Monoisotopic_Mass   Predicted_NET   Tryptic_Name
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   MTMDK   1   624,2611054 0,1124  t1.1
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   MTMDKSELVQK 2   1308,6417266    0,2304  t1.2
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   MTMDKSELVQKAK   3   1507,7737968    0,2278  t1.3
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   MTMDKSELVQKAKLAEQAER    4   2305,1769438    0,3107  t1.4
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   SELVQK  5   702,3911854 0,1286  t2.1
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   SELVQKAK    6   901,5232556 0,1294  t2.2
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   SELVQKAKLAEQAER 7   1698,9264026    0,2544  t2.3
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   SELVQKAKLAEQAERYDDMAAAMK    8   2695,330871 0,3435  t2.4
sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN   AKLAEQAER   9   1014,5457814    0,1198  t3.2
IPI:80000000.1  MGSTSEK 1   738,321789  0,0756  t1.1
IPI:80000001.1  MFLCSSFIFHHDCEASPAMLNCG 2   2559,0512972    0,5426  t1.1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks and cheers

Comment: To clarify: yes my Perl is a little rusty and I did not use MT in a loooong time. The last time I implemented it using fork(), but the way I understand fork(), it does not apply here since it creates a new instance of the whole program including all arrays. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please, use [`threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and not the long-deprecated (and vanished in 5.10) Thread module.  Please also use `strict` and `warnings`.  Then show us what doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the notice, I was following the tutorial on http://www.xav.com/perl/lib/Pod/perlthrtut.html#basic thread support, so now I switched to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been working on the code after switching to the "threads" module as recommended by pilcrow (Thank you :) ) and it seems that spawning the threads works fine now. However, what does not seem to work properly is waiting for the spawned threads to finish (see below). Currently, I use threads->detach() since I do not need any return values from my threads and printing to STDOUT is the only thing they are supposed to do. When I run the program, this is the output I get:

```
Threads:    3
Reference:  testRef.txt
peptide DB: testDB.txt
----------------
Loading reference...
Done!
Length:1999
Loading peptide database...
Done!
Length:1999
Starting analysis...
(This can take a while)
----------------
1999    1   0   666 666
main: 0 666
createThr: 0    666
main: 666   1332
createThr: 666  1332
peptideCheck: 0 666
MTMDKSELVQK
main: 1332  1999
createThr: 1332 1999
peptideCheck: 666   1332
MAVMAPRTLLLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMR
----------------
Finished!
peptideCheck: 1332  1999
THVIWGTSKDFGISGFR
```

From that I conclude that my threads are generated properly with the correct parameters, but when it comes to computation, they are disrupted because the main script finishes. I though when using detach() this does not happen, so have I missed something or do I use it the wrong way?

Here's the new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    use threads;
    use threads::shared;
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $minLength :shared   = $ARGV[0];
    my $numThreads          = $ARGV[1];
    my $reference_File      = $ARGV[2];
    my $peptideDB_File      = $ARGV[3];

    if ($minLength eq ""){$minLength = 6;}

    print STDERR ("Threads:\t".$numThreads."\n");
    print STDERR ("Reference:\t".$reference_File."\n");
    print STDERR ("peptide DB:\t".$peptideDB_File."\n----------------\n");
    print STDERR ("Loading reference...\n");

# Load reference peptides
    open (REF,$reference_File) || die ("File not found!");
    my @reference :shared = ();
    while (<REF>) {
        chomp;
        my @refPeptide = split("\t");
        if($refPeptide[1] eq "Sequence") {next;}
        push(@reference,$refPeptide[1]);
    }
    close (REF);
    print STDERR ("Done!\n");
    print STDERR ("Length:".@reference."\n");
    print STDERR ("Loading peptide database...\n");

# Open peptide DB to check
    open (PEP,$peptideDB_File) || die ("File not found!");
    my @dbID :shared  = ();
    my @dbPep :shared = ();
    while (<PEP>) {
        chomp;
        my @dbPeptide = split("\t");
        if($dbPeptide[1] eq "Sequence") {next;}
        push(@dbID,$dbPeptide[0]);
        push(@dbPep,$dbPeptide[1]);
    }
    close (PEP);
    print STDERR ("Done!\n");
    print STDERR ("Length:".@dbPep."\n");
    print STDERR ("Starting analysis...\n");
    print STDERR ("(This can take a while)\n");
    print STDERR ("----------------\n");

#my %ref = map { $_ => 1 } @reference;

    my $dbLength        = @dbPep;
    my $rest            = $dbLength % $numThreads;
    my $chunkStart      = 0;
    my $chunkLength     = ($dbLength - $rest) / $numThreads;
    my $chunkEnd        = $chunkLength;

    print STDERR ($dbLength."\t".$rest."\t".$chunkStart."\t".$chunkLength."\t".$chunkEnd."\n");

    #&peptideCheck($chunkStart,$chunkEnd);

    for (my $i=0;$i<$numThreads;$i++) {
        if ($i == $numThreads-1) {$chunkEnd += $rest;};
        print STDERR ("main: ".$chunkStart."\t".$chunkEnd."\n");
        createThr($chunkStart, $chunkEnd);
        $chunkStart += $chunkLength;
        $chunkEnd   += $chunkLength;
    }
    print STDERR ("----------------\nFinished!\n");

    sub peptideCheck {
        my @params = @_;
        print STDERR ("peptideCheck: ".$params[0]."\t".$params[1]."\n");
        for (my $j=$params[0]; $j<$params[1];$j++){
            if (length($dbPep[$j]) < $minLength) {next;}
            print ($dbPep[$j]."\n");
            if ( grep { $_ eq $dbPep[$j]} @reference ) {
                next;
            }
            else {
                print STDOUT (">".$dbID[$j]."\n".$dbPep[$j]."\n");
            }
        }
    }

    sub createThr {
        my @thrParams = @_;
        print STDERR ("createThr: ".$thrParams[0]."\t".$thrParams[1]."\n");
        my $thr = threads->create(\&peptideCheck, $thrParams[0], $thrParams[1]);
        $thr->detach();
    }
```

Comment: Then store thread "handles" in an array and use join to wait for running threads.

Comment: After experimenting with the threads, I found a solution in another post, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447638/simple-parallel-processing-in-perl

So from the looks of it, threading now works somehow, but the computation time is almost 3 times higher than before...
Any suggestions why this is the case?

Comment: Here's the code:
`my @jobs;
 for (my $i=0;$i<$numThreads;$i++) {
     if ($i == $numThreads-1) {$chunkEnd += $rest;};
     push @jobs, threads->create(\&peptideCheck, $chunkStart, $chunkEnd);
     $chunkStart += $chunkLength;
     $chunkEnd       += $chunkLength;
}
$_->join for @jobs;`